# Draw comparator and invert it

Tags: circuitikz, anchor

I have drawn an error amplifier but I wanted to invert the terminals.
And how to draw a comparator in `circuitikz`. There's a screenshot attached.

[image: I'm trying to draw voltage mode control of Buck converter]

```
        \begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{circuitikz}
                \draw (-3,4) to[battery1] node[ground]{} (-3,0);
                \draw (-3.5,2) node[left]{$V_\mathrm{in}$};
                \draw (-3,4) to[short] (2,4);
                \draw (2.5,4) node[nigfete, rotate=90] (fet) {} (fet.S) to[L,l=$L$] (7,4);
                \draw (6.5,4) to[C,l=$C$,*-](6.5,0);
                \draw (6.5,4) to[short] (8.5,4) to[R,l=$R_1$](8.5,2) to[R,l=$R_2$] node[ground]{} (8.5,0);
                \draw (4,2) node[nigfete](fet){}
                 (fet.D) to[short,-*] (4,4) 
                 (fet.S) to[short,-*](4,0);
                \draw (4,0) node[ground]{}to[short] (6.5,0);
                \draw (4,-2) node[op amp, rotate=180](opamp){};
                \draw (opamp.+) to[battery1,l=$V_{ref}$] node[ground]{}(6.2,-1.5);
                \draw (opamp.-) to[short] (7.5,-2.5)to[short](7.5,2) to[short,-*](8.5,2);
                \draw (1,-2) node[op amp, rotate=180](comp){};
        \end{circuitikz}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a bipole you could use `[mirror]`, but for a node you use `[xscale=-1]` instead of `[rotate=180]`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
                \draw (-3,4) to[battery1] node[ground]{} (-3,0);
                \draw (-3.5,2) node[left]{$V_\mathrm{in}$};
                \draw (-3,4) to[short] (2,4);
                \draw (2.5,4) node[nigfete, rotate=90] (fet) {} (fet.S) to[L,l=$L$] (7,4);
                \draw (6.5,4) to[C,l=$C$,*-](6.5,0);
                \draw (6.5,4) to[short] (8.5,4) to[R,l=$R_1$](8.5,2) to[R,l=$R_2$] node[ground]{} (8.5,0);
                \draw (4,2) node[nigfete](fet){}
                 (fet.D) to[short,-*] (4,4) 
                 (fet.S) to[short,-*](4,0);
                \draw (4,0) node[ground]{}to[short] (6.5,0);
                \draw (4,-2) node[op amp, xscale=-1](opamp){};
                \draw (opamp.+) to[battery1,l=$V_{ref}$] ++(1.2,0) node[ground]{};
                \draw (opamp.-) -| (7.5,2) to[short,-*](8.5,2);
                \draw (1,-2) node[op amp, xscale=-1](comp){};
        \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Congratulation! Very good and I upvote you.